# Removing the commas from string in c#

Tags: c#

I have this string:

AppleBanana

With C# code, I was managed to bring like this:

**Apple,Banana,**

But I don't want the last comma in it.

So for that I used:

```
string obj = myVar.Trim().Trim(','); // this is just to remove the whitespace and trailing comma
```

But nothing happens. My string is still the same i.e. it shows **Apple,Banana,**.

Then I tried this:

```
if (myVar.EndsWith(", "))
    myVar= myVar.Remove(myVar.Length - 1); // but this removes all the commas from the string.
```

Where am I missing?

Comment: You can use `string` method `.TrimEnd(',')`

Comment: @dcg Even tried that too.. Doesn't work... Any bdw why Downvote??

Comment: Need some more info here. So `obj` still has the ending `,`? Or were you expecting `myVar` to be updated?

Comment: [`myVar.Trim().Trim(','); ` is working ...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mBiC9V) ... so please write what is wrong (in english) ...  now the question is unclear

Comment: Did you do `myVar = myVar.TrimEnd(',')`? and didn't work? Also notice that you are checking for `", "` with a trailing space. BTW, with `TrimEnd` you don't need the `if`.

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica, yes obj still has the ending comma

Comment: You can use regex to replace the commas globally for either spaces or an empty char and then trim what's left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    string s = "Apple,Banana,";
    s = s.Remove(s.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's clear that you're working with comma-delimited data, so treat it as such. Split it into an array. While you're splitting it, you can remove empty entries, which will have the effect of ignoring the final comma.

```
var list = myVar.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.IgnoreEmptyEntries);
```

If you need it as a comma-separated string again, join it:

```
var myVar = string.Join(",", list);
```

Comment: Nope, it still shows the same. It is AppleBanana

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code that you are using that demonstrates that "it still shows the same." For example, a logging or `Console.WriteLine` statement that provides the problematic output. I suspect you are not assigning the result of the string operations properly.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last character.

```cs
string obj = myVar.Remove(myVar.Length - 1);
```

### Update

@JohnWu solution is better, more coherent, more robust.